# Como obtengo primer dia y último día del mes en Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Estoy teniendo problemas con establecer el primer y último día del mes en curso.

-Esto es lo que tengo en mi TEMPLATE

```
<v-menu 
    v-model="menu2"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    max-width="290px"
    min-width="auto"
>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="computedDateFormattedDesde"
            persistent-hint
            prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
        ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
    v-model="date_hasta"
    no-title
    @input="menu2 = false"
    ></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

-En mi data, tengo lo siguiente:

```
data() {
    return {
        date_desde: 'Aqui deseo obtener el primer día del mes',
        menu1: false,
        menu2: false,
    }
}
```

-En el computed :

```
computed: {
    computedDateFormattedDesde () {
        return this.formatDateDesde(this.date_desde)
    }, 
}
```

-En el metodo :

```
 formatDateDesde (date) {
    if (!date) return null

    const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`
 }
```

Necesito obtener en el model la primer día y última fecha del mes.
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Quieres calcular eso dentro de la función `date` o quieres calcularlo en `formatDateDesde` y acceder a ese resultado en `date`?

Comment: Hola @Fedex7501. Actualmente en el metodo data el valor date_desde , esta vacío, podría hacer el calculo ahí mismo o en el método formatDateDesde , ya que, lo que deseo es pintarlo en v-model.

Answer (score 0):

```
formatDateDesde (date) {
    if (!date) return null

    const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')

    this.date_desde = new Date(year, month - 1, 1) //Fecha del primer día del mes
    this.date_desde = `${year}/${month}/${this.date_desde.getDate()}` //Formateamos la fecha

    this.date_hasta = new Date(year, month, 0) //Fecha del último día del mes
    this.date_hasta = `${year}/${month}/${this.date_hasta.getDate()}` //Formateamos la fecha

    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Una pregunta y en el data "date_desde" que debería pasarle, ya que al estar ' ', no me muestra nada. Gracias

Comment: @JosephMarchena deberías pasarle this.date_desde

Comment: .Es aquí donde me indicas ? para pasarle .  data() {
    return {
        date_desde: '?????',
        menu1: false,
        menu2: false,
    }
} .Porque me muestra indefinido, ya que no le estoy pasando valor al data.

Comment: Si `data()` no es un método de la clase entonces `this` va a ser indéfinido. Tendría que ver tu código completo para saber como pasarle los datos.